# How do I embed a video in my question or answer?

Tags: support

This is a "help" question to explain how to embed a video in your question or answer.  Please feel free to use the Answer space to test this functionality out!

---

You can embed a Youtube video in your question, simply by placing a link to the Youtube video directly in the answer as open text.

The link has to be to [https://youtube.com/[yourvideo];](https://youtube.com/%5Byourvideo%5D;) it does *not* work with some URL shorteners.

---

As a reminder, videos are welcome in questions or answers, but they should not be the only source of information in that question or answer.  If you have a question about something in the video, please explain in words what is happening; and if you have an answer that relies on a video to show something, please also explain in words as best you can.  Videos may be taken down at any time, and videos are not accessible for some users.

Answer (score 1):

Examples that work:

(Bare URL)

(Some text before the URL)

This is Michael Jordan's Flu Game, the greatest basketball performance of all time!

Isn't he amazing?

(URL shortener - seems to work with the default one)

Examples that do NOT work:

(This has the link behind the words, but since the link isn't part of the actual text of the question, it isn't embedded)

[Michael Jordan's Flu Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NXUsH-_1Jc)